# 'module' object has no attribute 'DataFrame'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(12,2), columns=['Apples', 'Oranges'] )
df['Categories'] = pd.Series(list('AAAABBBBCCCC'))
pd.options.display.mpl_style = 'default'
df.boxplot(by='Categories')
```

I get the error:

```
'pandas' object has no attribute 'DataFrame'.
```

Any ideas on what is happening and how to fix this problem?

Comment: Is it possible you've named a variable `pd` somewhere by accident? Or imported something else `as pd` after `pandas`? If not, were there any errors when you installed `pandas`? Finally, any chance there are non-printable character in the middle of your code (say, because you edited it in Word instead of a text editor)?

Comment: Do you have a directory called pandas near where you are working?

Comment: Also make sure your file isn't called `pd.py`, and that you don't have a module called `pd.py` somewhere that you're importing.

Comment: Remove the .pyc file from your working directory and execute the code again

Comment: if you file name is pandas*.py changes the file name but make sure your file name should not start from pandas*. issue will get resolved.  i was facing issue and this got fixed

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The code presented here doesn't show this discrepancy, but sometimes I get stuck when invoking `dataframe` in all lower case.

Switching to camel-case (`pd.DataFrame()`) cleans up the problem.

Comment: I was doing the same mistake, but with `Dataframe` instead of `dataframe`.

Comment: I also did a typo of using pandas.dataFrame, I changed it to pandas.DataFrame and it worked for me. Thanks Daniel Klaus.

Answer (score 50):

Please check if:

a) you've named a file 'pandas.py' in the same directory as your script, or

b) another variable called 'pd' is used in your program.

Comment: I started writing test code for pandas and accidentally created pandas.py for testing which was resulting in the following bug. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also named the file as pandas.py

Answer (score 26):

Change the file name if your file name is like `pandas.py` or `pd.py`, as, otherwise, the file name will shadow the real name. In this case, an error message may also be raised, citing a possible circular import.

Comment: By far the best answer. I had the same issue here: 57218531 and accidentally saw this now.

Comment: Yes, you need to change the file name if you have pandas.py or pad.py.Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 7):

For me he problem was that my script was called `pandas.py` in the folder `pandas` which obviously messed up my imports.

Comment: Same problem, make sure that your script don't have name same as package :|

Answer (score 4):

There may be two causes:

1. It is case-sensitive: DataFrame ....    Dataframe, dataframe will not work.
2. You have not install pandas (`pip install pandas`) in the python path.

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure that your file name should not be `panda.py` or `pd.py`.
Also, make sure that panda is there in your `Lib/site-packages` directory, if not that you need to install panda using below command line:

```
pip install pandas
```

if you work with proxy then try calling below in command prompt:

```
python.exe -m pip install pandas --proxy="YOUR_PROXY_IP:PORT"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar problem, **'int' object has no attribute 'DataFrame'**,

This was because i have mistakenly used pd as a variable in my code and assigned an integer to it, while using the same pd as my pandas dataframe object by declaring - `import pandas as pd.`

I realized this, and changed my variable to something else, and fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

I recieved a similar error:

> AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'DataFrame'

The cause of my error was that I ran pip install of pandas as root, and my user did not have permission to the directory.

My fix was to run:

> sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages

Comment: I think this is  better:
sudo find /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +
sudo find /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +